# Odds of occurrence in game of Rummikub

Tags: probability

**Caveat:** Not a formal math guy; just enjoy numbers. Please feel free to improve my question with official math syntax, as needed.

Rummikub is a Rummy-style game played with tiles. It's basically 2 decks of cards (colors instead of suits) plus 2 jokers, for a total of 106 tiles.

The game starts with each player drawing 14 tiles.

Last night, my son played with my parents and drew both jokers at the start of 2 consecutive games.

Assuming he drew first each game (thereby, I think, eliminating the effect of other players), what are the odds of this occurring?

I think I could figure out the answer if there was only 1 joker in the pile:

1. 1/106
2. 1/105
3. 1/104
4. etc...

That should (I think) add up to a roughly 14% chance of drawing a joker.

I am stumped, though, as to how to incorporate the probability logic for the addition of a 2nd joker, and the requirement of drawing both of them.

I think that, once you find the odds of the first game, you simply square them to get the overall odds of doing it consecutively, right?

Comment: How do the players draw the tiles? Is it that they take turns drawing one tile each, or each takes all 14 of the tiles at once? And I presume it's a three-player game?

Comment: In most real-life games, it's just everyone drawing simultaneously. That's why I wanted to just focus on a single player drawing first. Otherwise, I think the math gets very, very difficult. So, just assume the player is drawing all 14 tiles first, from the whole 106 tile set.

Comment: I'm a little late to the conversation here but I figured I'd put in my two cents. I was taught that each player is to draw a tile and compare the value. Whomever has the highest (or lowest) tile draws their 14 first. The remaining players then choose theirs in CCW order (or by thd rank of their singular tile). That being said, the probabilities are a little different. This is addressed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4020870/373416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of drawing $k=2$ jokers in $n=14$ draws without replacement from $N=106$ tiles with $K=2$ jokers is conveniently given by the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution):
$$P(\operatorname{hgeom}(N,K,n)=k)=\frac{\binom Kk\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom Nn}$$
$$P(\operatorname{hgeom}(106,2,14)=2)=\frac{\binom22\binom{106-2}{14-2}}{\binom{106}{14}}=\frac{13}{795}=1.6\%$$
However, this only applies for one game. For two games, your logic is right – we can square the probability just derived because the games are independent:
$$P=\left(\frac{13}{795}\right)^2=\frac{169}{632025}=0.027\%$$

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer! I've seen the notation you're using there, but I am not sure what it is. It appears to be a probability notation. What is it called?

Comment: What I wrote is the usual way to express sampling from a random variable. We can treat the drawing of tiles as a random variable $X$; the notation $P(X=k)$ then means "the probability that a sample from $X$ is $k$".

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how to calculate the answer. I do not understand how to get from "(2 2)(106-2 14-2)" to "13". I am assuming it is correct, but how do you expand that notation so as to do the calculation? Or what is it called, so I can research that answer myself? Thanks!

Comment: Look up "binomial coefficient" wherever you feel like it. I understand that some use $^nC_k$ where I use $\binom nk$, but they are both shorthand for $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.